# error: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Tags: c

```
int calc_stats(char pinax[N][M],int len_pinax)
{
    int i,j;
    int letters;
    char space[]=" ";

    for(i=0;i<len_pinax;i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(pinax[i]);j++){
            if(strcmp(pinax[i][j],space)!=0){
                letters++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of the words in text is: %d and the sum of the letters is: %d",len_pinax,letters)

    return 0;
}
```

So I wrote this code and this error pops up when I try to compile the program:

```
error: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `pinax[i][j]` is a `char` but strcmp requires a `char *`. It's not entirely clear what that should be as you have not provided a complete [mre] and have not even explained what the code should do. But perhaps it shoujld be `if (pinax[i][j] == ' ')`

Comment: If your code is meant to be counting letters, you should probably be using `#include <ctype.h>` and `isalpha()`.  There are lots of characters which are not spaces that are not letter either — digits, punctuation, and so on.

Comment: It is supposed to go through some strings that are stored in an array and skip the spaces